# Escapes quotes fine on command line but doesn't work when assigned to variable

Tags: regex, ksh, quote

Very simple problem but I can't see what the issue is. In ksh shell escaping a quote in searchstring works differently when assigned to a variable versus when used from the command line. All the examples I can find demonstrate using the command line so couldn't find a match for what is a very basic problem.

Both work fine:

> cat access_443_log.2020-01-09 | grep 'HTTP/1.1" 200 '
>
> cat access_443_log.2020-01-09 | grep "HTTP/1.1\" 200 "

But doing it when either is assigned to the variable searchstring

> searchstring='HTTP/1.1" 200 ' **or** 
>   searchstring="HTTP/1.1\" 200 "
>
> cat access_443_log.2020-01-09 | grep $searchstring

**Error:** grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 200.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add double quote to your variable, like this.

```
cat access_443_log.2020-01-09 | grep "$searchstring"
```